# store.get("userOptionOptOut") get from wrong path

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, store

I am using electron-store version 5.2.0 for Angular project.
I would like to know where is the path or how to get the path when store.get("userOptionOptOut").

In app.component.ts:

```
const Store = (window as any).require('electron-store');
const store = new Store();

const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');
```

In app.component.ts constructor:

```
if (store.get('userOptionOptOut') !== undefined) {
      this.userOptionOptOut = store.get('userOptionOptOut');
      this.settingService.patchSettingBySettingPath(this.dataCollectionSetting, this.userOptionOptOut);
}
```

I have the config.json (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\XXXX\XXXX\AppConfig\AppName) file that records the setting:

```
{
    "userOptionOptOut":  "On"
}
```

But I have this error (Image below) when I would like to check the path so I added the code

```
const { app } = window.require('electron');

  console.log(app.getAppPath());
  console.log(app.getPath("userData"));
  console.log(app.getPath("appData"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found something wrong with the path. My desired path is here, so I need to set the path to the correct path in main.ts

```
 if (process.platform === 'win32') {
  app.setPath ('userData', app.getPath('appData') + '\\XXXX\\XXXX\\AppConfig\\' + 
 app.getName());
 } else {
  app.setPath ('userData', require('os').homedir() + '/.XXXX/XXXX/AppConfig/' + 
app.getName());
}
```